# oracle spatial create sdo_geometery error

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

This fails ...

```
select count(a.ID)  
from Data a 
where SDO_RELATE(a.Coord,sdo_geometry
      ('POLYGON ((107.6867156260575300 41.0816926039780700, 107.6087554442719400 40.4704473540093090, 109.6431093571823100 40.3708796208939300, 109.5322666429356100 41.2350048095779300, 107.6867156260575300 41.0816926039780700))'
      ,4326)
      ,'mask = ANYINTERACT') = 'TRUE';
```

... with this error ...

```
ORA-29925: cannot execute MDSYS.SDO_INDEX_METHOD_10I.ODCIINDEXSTART
ORA-06540: PL/SQL: compilation error
ORA-06553: PLS-907: cannot load library unit MDSYS.SDO_TOPO_GEOMETRY
       (referenced by MDSYS.SDO_INDEX_METHOD_10I)
```

... but this is ok:

```
select * 
from Data a ,Data2 b 
where  SDO_RELATE(a.Coord,b.Coord,'mask = ANYINTERACT') = 'TRUE';
```

Comment: Helping you debug your Spatial configuration will require some specialist expertise.  I suggest you try [the Oracle Technet Spatial forum](https://community.oracle.com/community/database/oracle-database-options/spatial/content?filterID=contentstatus[published]~objecttype~objecttype[thread]&customTheme=otn) as you're more likely to find gurus there.

Comment: thanks for you help,I've got help in Oracle forum